# Is it possible to upgrade from windows phone 8.1 (appx) to windows phone 8.1 silverlight (xap) and retain the application data

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

We had built an app using windows phone runtime 8.1, as you all know during build we get a .appx as output, but this .appx is not deployable on windows phone 8, as some of our customers still want to continue using windows phone 8, we are trying to port our windows phone runtime app to windows phone silverlight, but the question is can the existing users who are using the windows phone runtime app upgrade their app from windows phone 8.1 runtime to windows phone 8.1 silverlight ? assume that we only need to side load the app, we are not going to submit it to store.

Comment: There is no official way to port from Win-Runtime to Silverlight (API's are not backwards compatible). Even more soo, you are encouraged to move from Silverlight to Win-Runtime. At this point in time there shouldn't be a lot of people running WP 8, they should have an update available  for them to get to WP 8.1. Even more soo Windows 10 for Phones is just around the corner. 

Answering your question, it is very likely that you will have to rewrite big chunk of your code, however I'm not sure it's worth while.  

PS. Runtime to Silverlight would be considered as downgrade in this case.

Comment: Runtime to silverlight can be considered as downgrade, however our actual requirement is to retain the application data when updating the windows phone runtime app with the silverlight one with the same product guid and package family name

Comment: In this case I would consider a migration experience. But it all depends on your data structure and storage solution rather then the runtime that is written for. I'm still having trouble to understand why would you do this, but hey handle it as a challenge.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a tiny test app and experimenting. I wouldn't expect it to work given the atypical circumstances of what you want to do.

Comment: Below error is encountered during the downgrade of a native windows runtime app to windows phone 8.1 Silverlight app 

Installation of application failed, XAP signature is not valid or the WP manifest file is invalid, Re-sign with valid signature and fix the manifest file. 

However when I uninstall the windows phone runtime app and try installing the Silverlight app a fresh, this error is not encountered. 

essentially it is a case of downgrading .appx deployment with Silverlight 8.1 xap deployment